# How to fix returned NULL from function, where is the error?

Tags: php, function, variables

I would like to return a static string using function, But nothing returned

This function needs to return "I am"
So where is the error ?
First i tried echo nothing returned
then print,print_r also nothing
finally var_export or var_dump returns NULL

```
// Here is the function
function w_is_the_error() {
    global $where;
    return $where;
}

// I executed here
$the_error = w_is_the_error($where = 'I Am');

// When doing var_export it returns NULL
var_export($the_error);
```

Comment: Your function doesn't take any parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Answer (score 0):

Because that's not how you send or accept function arguments.

```
function w_is_the_error($where) {
    return $where;
}

// I executed here
$the_error = w_is_the_error('I Am');

// When doing var_export it returns NULL
var_export($the_error);
```

`global` is a crutch. Don't use it, use arguments.